# Default migration fail in Azure: Multiple primary key defined (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `password_reset_tokens` add primary key (`email`))

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed a Laravel application in Azure App Service. Everything works well in development and production. However, when I run migrations in production, it fails when it reaches the `password_reset_token_password` migration. Below are my error and migration respectively.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `password_reset_tokens` add primary key (`email`))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:795
    791▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    792▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    793▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    794▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 795▕             throw new QueryException(
    796▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    797▕             );
    798▕         }
    799▕     }

      +9 vendor frames 

  10  database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table.php:14
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic("create")
      +24 vendor frames 

  35  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

Migration

```
return new class extends Migration
{
  /**
   * Run the migrations.
   */
  public function up(): void
  {
    Schema::create('password_reset_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->string('email')->primary();
      $table->string('token');
      $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Reverse the migrations.
   */
  public function down(): void
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('password_reset_tokens');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL version 8.0 and above, Generated Invisible Primary Keys(GIPK) is enabled by default for all the Azure Database for MySQL Flexible Servers.

Disabling GIPK fixes the issue, and to do so follow the following steps:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal, then locate your Azure Database for MySQL -
   Flexible Server.
2. Under the SETTINGS section, click Server parameters to open the server
   parameters page for the Azure Database for MySQL - Flexible Server.
3. Search for `sql_generate_invisible_primary_key` and update it to `off`.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-limitations#generated-invisible-primary-keys